# I need advice on which graphic card brand to buy to get long term support from Ubuntu 16.04 onward

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, graphics, amd-graphics, lts

I have reached a point where I need to upgrade a couple of Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS box to Ubuntu 16.04LTS. I have been searching this forum and others but most of the answer for this are outdated (~2014).

To be able to upgrade and get the OpenGL working, I need to replace the AMD HD 6670 I have bu something recent. I would like advices on which card (nvidia or AMD) to purchase to make sure that I'll get the longest support for the new graphic card I need to buy. Shall I go for let say and AMD RX serie or a FirePro or a NVidia Quadro or GTX serie?

I have personally experience some pretty horrible glitches with drivers from both brand so I don't mind going for either brand. The issue I have had over the recent years with AMD is that they are very quick at turning mid-range cards in the legacy box that does not support further update/upgrade!! This is pain! I use those PC for work not game, I need long term support, I cannot change card every 2 years. Nvidia drivers have been a pain to get something stable with 2 displays.

Thanks

Rv

Comment: Sorry we do not provide hardware suggestions and recommedations. "I use those PC for work not game" you don't need a graphics card like a "MD RX serie or a FirePro or a NVidia Quadro or GTX serie" Overkill for work related activities. Get a basic intel or nVidia for under 100 euro. AMD has no love for Linux so forget about that one.

Comment: For the work I do, I need a dedicated graphic card. OpenGL does not work with the pro software I use on the integrated intel graphic chip. Believe me I have tried. What do you mean by "basic nVidia"? How do you want user to make good use of Ubuntu if they are unsure about which hardware they should use?? I found it puzzling that hardware is not of interest to this forum, if it was outside the interest of the users there would not be so many questions about the difficulties to find hardware compatible with Linux. No surprise that Linux never took off as an OS!

Comment: OK I edit my questions: Where can I find an up to date list of the graphic cards which have compatible drivers with Ubuntu 16.04LTS? NB: I also need those cards to be likely supported in a future that does not end in 6 months!